# Cell runs out of tableview iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

[image]
[image]

I implement the table view on the right. And as u can see, the cells go out the table view. (It even runs all the way down to the bottom)
I have tried set cell cliptoBounds = true but doesn't work

```
var boxes = ["Box 1", "Box 2", "Box 3", "Box 4", "Box 5"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.historyTableViewOutlet.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HistoryCell", for: indexPath) as! HistoryVC

    cell.boxName.text = boxes[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

In the HistoryVC: `class HistoryVC: UITableViewCell {

```
//MARK: Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var placeholderView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var boxName: UILabel!
}
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Does the boxes refers to different cells?

Comment: Make sure you have added label in cell.

Comment: have you tried to increase section height

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: please add some valid code

Comment: I have added the code, please see it above

Comment: Why do I need to increase section height?

Comment: No, the cell contains a view, which contains a label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to create a UIView for section header. 
First: make sure your tableView in the Main Storyboard is declared with type Plain.
Second: implement 2 methods of TableViewDelegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.tableView.frame.minX, y: self.tableView.frame.minY, width: self.tableView.frame.size.width, height: 28))
    let label = UILabel(frame: header.frame)
    header.addSubview(label)

    label.text = "SECTION HEADER"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 230/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 0.9)
    return header
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 28
}
```

Sure you will want to customize that view for various sections. Just switch inside the delegate method between section numbers and assign views/text/labels/colors at your choice. 
Once you scroll through cells within 1 section, its header will be glued to the top layout border.

PS After new details: you should put a constraint to clip the tableView to the top layout border. Cells do not run away from a tableView. They are scrolled up, beyond the visible zone, within the scrollView that contains the tableView. Just put exact constraints to fix the position of the tableView. Here:

[image: adjusting top constraint]

Comment: Apparently the problem is that I set masktoBounds = false so it run off. Anyway thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Try to give your table's border some color so you can see the changing. Then try cliptobonds property of tableview not cell as you said in query.